# How to write to text file on windows C dirve using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to write a file on C drive on windows using Qt c++
what I try

```
QFile file("C:/key.txt");
if (!file.exists())
{
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    file.write("0");
    file.close();
}
```

but nothing was written on C i think i should give it admin permissions so it can write to C drive but i search and found QFile::setpermissions
but it did't solve the problem too 

so any idea to solve my problem please 
 Thanks in Avdance

Comment: Have you stepped through to ensure the code inside the conditional is getting executed?

Comment: You should check whether `open` and `write` succeeded.

Comment: yes the function executed i try it on D:/key.txt and it work and made the file with no problem

Comment: yeah, surely a permissions issue then as the answers say.

Comment: You could test for the boolean success at each step, and get the error code with `file.error()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run your application with administrator privileges to write to `C:`. It requires to by pass UAC. To do that, embed the manifest:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /MANIFESTUAC:"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'"
```

or you can adjust your [application manifest](http://blog.strixcode.com/2010/08/embedding-application-manifest-and.html):

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>
```

Comment: where can i find this file please

Answer (score 1):

Writing directly on the C: drive requires admin privileges. Either change the folder or start the application as admin.